# How can I release a CVPixelBuffer after passing it to CoreImage/UIKit in Swift?

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, core-image, core-foundation

I'm using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(_:_:_:_:_:_:_:_:_:_:)` to read a 24-bit BMP from disk:

```
var data = try! Data(contentsOf: url.appendingPathExtension(for: .bmp))
data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (unsafeMutableRawBufferPointer: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
  var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
  CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    imageWidth,
    imageHeight,
    kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB,
    unsafeMutableRawBufferPointer.baseAddress!,
    bytesPerRow,
    nil, nil, nil,
    &pixelBuffer
  )
}
```

I need to convert it to JPEG, but all the methods I've tried leak, i.e.:

```
try! UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!))
    .jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)!
    .write(to: someUrl)
```

and:

```
try! CIContext().writeJPEGRepresentation(
    of: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!),
    to: someUrl,
    colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
)
```

`autoreleasepool` doesn't help:

```
autoreleasepool {
  var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
  CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    imageWidth,
    imageHeight,
    kCVPixelFormatType_24RGB,
    unsafeMutableRawBufferPointer.baseAddress!,
    bytesPerRow,
    nil, nil, nil,
    &pixelBuffer
  )
  try! UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!))
    .jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)!
    .write(to: someUrl)
}
```

And none of the `*Release` methods are available, they produce compiler errors like: `'CFRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed`.

The issue seems to be the pointer gets retained when any of the JPEG-related methods get called. This leaks:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!))
    .jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)!
```

But this doesn't:

```
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!))
```

Same with Core Image. This doesn't leak:

```
CIContext().createCGImage(CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!), from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
```

But this does:

```
CIContext().writeJPEGRepresentation(
    of: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!),
    to: someUrl,
    colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
)
```

I guess I need to release the memory by passing `CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback` to seems to `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes`, but it's not clear to me how to use it in this case. Most examples suggests doing something like:

```
let releaseCallBack: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = { _, pointer in
  if let pointer = pointer {
     free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: pointer))
  }
}
```

But it makes the `autoreleasepool` call to throw because it's trying to free memory that's not there any more, and removing it makes other objects to keep leaking. Manually calling `deallocate` on the point doesn't help either

Comment: Have you tried loading the bitmap into a `CIImage` directly via `CIImage(contentsOf: url)`? It might not be necessary to create a `CVPixelBuffer` first. Or do you need that for something else?

Comment: @FrankRupprecht I need the `CVPixelBuffer` because the file is a 24-bit BMP, which isn't supported by Core Image. Maybe there's another API I can use to load it? [Here is the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71956907/is-it-possible-to-load-a-24-bits-bmp-with-a-native-ios-api)

Comment: Ah yes, I remember. Are you doing all the conversions inside the `withUnsafeMutableBytes` block?

Comment: @FrankRupprecht yes, I tried moving things outside, but I didn't see any improvement, maybe I missed something